# How to make table with different spacing and rounded corners

Tags: html, css, html-table

My attempt is to create a table with unique spacing, in this case it would be 3 columns but in my first attempt I tried using rectangle and straight lines, the white spaces need to interact so I found it better and more obvious to try to use a table with custom css, below the example that I wish to mirror myself, I need to get to the reproduction of it.

[image]

my attempt with retancle is so bad like this

[image]

```
<div class="_idGenObjectLayout-1">
    <div id="_idContainer000" class="_idGenObjectStyleOverride-1">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="_idGenObjectLayout-1">
    <div id="_idContainer001" class="Quadro-de-gr-fico-b-sico _idGenObjectStyleOverride-2">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="_idGenObjectLayout-1">
    <div id="_idContainer002" class="Quadro-de-gr-fico-b-sico _idGenObjectStyleOverride-3">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="_idGenObjectLayout-1">
    <div id="_idContainer003" class="Quadro-de-gr-fico-b-sico _idGenObjectStyleOverride-4">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="_idGenObjectLayout-1">
    <div id="_idContainer004" class="Quadro-de-gr-fico-b-sico _idGenObjectStyleOverride-4">
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is how to reproduce this table properly with tables with divs/html/css

Comment: tried grid yet?

Comment: You can reproduce a table using a [`<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table). It just takes some time to figure out which CSS properties need to be edited. Also, it would help if you shared the CSS for your current attempt with `div`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
    .custom-table{
        border: 2px solid #6cb7e1;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        background-color: #287cb6;
        width: 410px;   
        height: 68px;
    }
    .custom-table td {
        border: 2px solid #6cb7e1;
    }
    .custom-table td span.line {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #3a86bd;
        display: block; 
    }
    .custom-table .arrow {
        width: 27px;
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .custom-table .arrow > span {
        border: 6px solid #d3a823;
        border-color: #d3a823 transparent transparent transparent;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform:translate(-50%, -50%)
    }
```

```html
<table class="custom-table">
  <tr>
    <td>
        <span class="line">line</span>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <span class="line">line</span>
        <span class="line">line</span>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2" class="arrow">
        <span></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I suggest you to use a combination of table, spans and css.

Comment: Thank you for Response, works like a charm but what's the best way to make this mobile responsive? I need there to be an automatic adjustment for each cell phone I will put this in the header of my html

Comment: You need to use media queries in CSS 5o make it responsive.